# Symfony 6.2 - EasyAdmin 4 phpunit test - Mandatory _locale

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony6, easyadmin

Within an application that I am building I got a admin with an locale variable (en/nl)

```
#[Route('/{_locale<%app.supported_locales%>}/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
```

Now everything is  working fine but I am creating unit tests to test the application. Easyadmin has a own $this->generateIndexUrl and when I try to request the url:

```
$this->client->request("GET", $this->generateIndexUrl(null, $this->getDashboardFqcn(), $this->getControllerFqcn()), [
   "_locale" => "en",
   "_route_params" => [
        "_locale" => "en"
   ]
]);
```

It gives me an Exception:
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException : Some mandatory parameters are missing ("_locale") to generate a URL for route "admin".

After searching and searching I can't find any method to set the 'mandatory' _locale.
Anyone got any ideas?

I tried several things:

```
// Set the locale
        $this->client->setServerParameters([
            'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en',
            '_locale' => 'en'
        ]);
```

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');
```

```
 $session = $this->createSession($this->client);

        $container = $this->client->getContainer();
        $sessionSavePath = $container->getParameter('session.save_path');
        $sessionStorage = new MockFileSessionStorage($sessionSavePath);

        $session = new Session($sessionStorage);
        $session->start();
        $session->set('_locale', 'en');
        $session->save();
```

All with not the desired effect. I got it working with an request in front of this one where I specify the route and _locale in an other way.

```
$url = $router->generate('admin', ['_locale' => 'en']);
        $this->client->request("GET", $url);
```

And strangely putting this one in front of the other, gives the desired effect because it takes the locale settings from this one.

I haven't found a method or variable yet to just set the locale with the EasyAdmin 4 method $this->generateIndexUrl.

I really hope someone has the answer how to give the route the required locale parameter within the Unit test and EasyAdmin

Comment: So after allot of testing I came across adminUrlGenerator. That EasyAdmin uses. With this code:

`$this->adminUrlGenerator->set('_locale', 'en');` 

It will work. But there is a catch. It doesn't use AdminUrlGenerator but the container for the set. Which is typehinted to be an object.

This is a problem within EasyAdmin.